# Please recommend some Python hashing algorithms

Tags: python

I'm doing a password hashing program in python. I need to make my hashing dynamic, i.e. each time I need to get different hashed code. I am using md5 library.

Comment: Every time you hash the _same thing_, you want to get a different result? That's **not a hash**.

Answer (score 3):

The information that you want can be found in [Python's hashlib module](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html). From the documentation:

> This module implements a common interface to many different secure hash and message digest 
>       algorithms. Included are the FIPS secure hash algorithms SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and 
>       SHA512 (defined in FIPS 180-2) as well as RSA’s MD5 algorithm (defined in Internet RFC 1321). 
>       The terms secure hash and message digest are interchangeable. Older algorithms were called 
>       message digests. The modern term is secure hash.

Comment: +1: Use `hashlib` unless there's some reason why you absolutely can't. `md5` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `salt` for that.

```
import hashlib
string = "password"
strsalt = "anyrandomvalue" #this can be generated.. etc.
hashlib.md5(string + strsalt).hexdigest()
```